# WPF Forms DataGridView ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagridview, contextmenu

I am trying to add a contextmenu to a Forms.DataGridView.
My attempt fails at `<wf:MenuItem Text="Save" Click="menuFEInsertLine_Click">` telling me that MenuItem cannot be added to MenuItemCollection. And also that String is expected.
How can i get this xaml to work?

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhFileEditorWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <local:DataGridViewEx x:Name="dgFileEditorWindow" AllowDrop="True" BackColor="White" BackgroundColor="White">
            <local:DataGridViewEx.ContextMenu>
                <wf:ContextMenu>
                    <wf:ContextMenu.MenuItems>
                        <wf:MenuItem Text="Save" Click="menuFEInsertLine_Click">
                            <wf:MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="star.png"/>
                            </wf:MenuItem.Icon>
                        </wf:MenuItem>
                        <wf:MenuItem Header="Save" Click="menuFEDeleteLine_Click">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="delete.png"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </wf:MenuItem>
```

Comment: The icon (`MenuItem.Icon`) in the second `MenuItem` does not have the `wf:` namespace... are you sure that's right?

Comment: That isn't right. I corrected it, but it still breaks at the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by overriding two methods of the DataGridView:

```
Private Sub dataGridView_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs
    ) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        Dim m As New Forms.ContextMenu()

        Dim hi As HitTestInfo = Me.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

        If hi.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            m.MenuItems.Add(New Forms.MenuItem("Insert Line", AddressOf CType(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow).menuFEInsertLine_Click))
        End If

        If hi.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
            If hi.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                m.MenuItems.Add("-")
            End If
            m.MenuItems.Add(New Forms.MenuItem("Insert Column", AddressOf CType(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow).menuFEInsertColumn_Click))
        End If

        m.Show(Me, New System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dataGridView_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs
    ) Handles Me.MouseMove

    Try
        Dim hi As HitTestInfo = Me.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        If hi IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(hi.ColumnIndex, hi.RowIndex, False, False, False)
        End If
    Catch ex As System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    End Try
End Sub
```